# Cannot select vertices from different object while in edit mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode

Whenever I enter edit mode, with 2 separate meshes (cubes), I can only select vertices/edges/faces of 1 mesh.

Example (the screen shot did not include the mouse cursor):

[image: edit mode]

Also, when I enter edit mode with both meshes selected, one of the meshes has a red border and cannot be selected (it also has this border in Object mode):

[image: edit mode with two objects selected]

Comment: The objects have to be one mesh in order to manipulate the vertices of both.

Comment: you can only edit the active one (the last selected ) that's how blender work

Comment: But I think there is a plugin that can enable editing meshes of multiple objects at the same time.

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-%28alpha-1%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing!

Comment: But that may confuse your workflow in blender, you need to learn first about objects and meshes. There may be better tools in blender for  specific needs, once you have basic knowledge how to use blender.

Comment: I don't plan On using it, I just need to know its there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to make the both meshes editable at the same time you need to join the objects in object mode while they are selected using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then both meshes will be available in edit mode.

Another way is to install [MultiEdit](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-version-5-Multiple-Objects-Editing/) addon that will allow to edit selected objects simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

You can only edit one mesh at a time.
Because these are two separate meshes, you will have to select both and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them to edit both at once.
If you want the final product to be two separate meshes, there is another command for turning every loose part of a mesh into its own mesh. (Pressing <kbd>P</kbd> > *all loose parts* while in edit mode).