# Selecting 2 objects in Edit mode

Tags: objects

I think I might have changed some cursor settings unintentionally. When I go to edit mode and try to select 2 objects using the shift key, it does not allow me to do so.. and also the mouse cursor changed to crosshair from a pointer. How can I get this back please?

The reason as to why I need to select both objects in edit mode is so that I can make use of the Knife Project tool Below is a screenshot of my settings

http://prntscr.com/bdvk45

Comment: Possible duplicate http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27543/23288

Comment: @FlamingThunder I checked that post already but I didn't find the answer to my question. They're not really the same

Comment: Are the two objects joined? If not you can't select both in edit mode with shift you need to join them first.

Comment: The linked question is indeed quite similar. You *can't* manipulate 2 objects in Edit mode at the same time, they've to be joined for that. "...To get this back..." to get what ? While in Edit mode, mouse cursor will change itselft to crosshair, it's normal behaviour. As for cutting with Knife Project there's no reason to have 2 objects in Edit mode, read how [to cut with it](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object).

Comment: ah Yes, sorry my bad. I thought something was wrong because I had just been playing with and changing the cursor options a few moments ago. I thought it was possible in edit mode to select 2 objects while they were not joined. This confirms that you cannot. Thank you for your help guys

Comment: I believe there is an addon that allows you to edit multiple objects at once, I can't remember what it is called off the top of my head though.