# Bizarre grey object within mesh area?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created a building mesh and I decided I wanted to stick another window in the outside.  I placed some loop cuts but when I went to delete the faces I noticed there is some grey object within the mesh which is not visible in wireframe mode - any ideas?

[image]

Comment: To clarify its the window directly in the middle of the SS

Comment: This is probably face of other side of the wall. Consider upload .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It isn't unfortunately, in wireframe this appears completely see through exactly the same as the other windows and I've even managed to face the surrounding window frame sides. I've also checked on all of the other walls deleting a face and this very odd grey structure which is unselectable appears.

Comment: Did you try exiting Edit mode for building and checking if there is another mesh in that place ?

Comment: Having done this it appears I have somehow managed to duplicate that entire building and it was this! Thanks it has been driving me mad!

Comment: This will be only guessing until we can see the .blend file

Comment: Edit post and upload your .blend file, so we can look at it.

Comment: Have fixed - trying Mr Zak's suggestion I selected it in object mode finally and I had somehow managed to duplicate the entire building structure. Sorry for wasting time and thanks for your help.

Comment: your welcome, I'm glad this is solved :-)

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38881/get-out-of-orange-selection-mode

Answer (score 2):

Unselectable geometry in Edit mode means there's another object in the scene located in the same place. You have several options to continue working on current object without anything messing around:

- enter [Local View](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#local-view) for selected object. Nothing except it will be visible. Note that you can activate Local View for several selected objects, not only one;
- exit Edit mode and enter Object mode. From there you'll be able to select another object (you could use [*Outliner*](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html) for navigating the objects in the scene in order to find what's needed) and either move it somewhere else or delete it altogether.
- join objects, which is done from Object mode too. Thus both objects will be editable at the same time, see [Cannot select vertices from different object while in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27543/cannot-select-vertices-from-different-object-while-in-edit-mode). Note that you could edit 2 different objects without joining them with [MultiEdit addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-%28alpha-1%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing);